# Can change style of the Excel cell?

Tags: c#, excel, microsoft-graph-api

I'd like to change the style of an Excel cell using the *Microsoft Graph SDK*. I tried the following code but it fails with exception:

> "InvalidArgument. The argument is invalid or missing or has an incorrect format."

```
var range = new WorkbookRange
{
    Format = new WorkbookRangeFormat
    {
        Font = new WorkbookRangeFont { Italic = true }
    }
};
await _client.Me.Drive.Items[fileId]
    .Workbook
    .Worksheets[worksheetId]
    .Range("A1")
    .Request()
    .PatchAsync(range);
```

I'm using [microsoft.graph](/questions/tagged/microsoft.graph) nuget **version 1.7.0**.

Comment: Can you add the complete error response? A Fiddler trace of the call over the wire would also be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference: [Range update format docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/rangeformat_update)

This is a bug. The call should look like the following if we were generating this as expected:

```
var fontPatchObject = new WorkbookRangeFont { Italic = true }
..Worksheets[worksheetId].Range("A1").Format.Font.Request().PatchAsync(fontPatchObject);
```

Here's the workaround:

```
var fileId = "yourFileId";
var worksheetId = "yourWorksheetId";
var requestUrl = $@"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{fileId}/workbook/worksheets/{worksheetId}/range(address='A1')/format/font";

WorkbookRangeFont font = new WorkbookRangeFont { Italic = true };

string workbookRangeFont = graphClient.HttpProvider.Serializer.SerializeObject(font);

// Create the request message and add the content.
HttpRequestMessage hrm = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("PATCH"), requestUrl);
hrm.Content = new StringContent(workbookRangeFont, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

// Authenticate (add access token) our HttpRequestMessage
await graphClient.AuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateRequestAsync(hrm);

// Send the request and get the response.
HttpResponseMessage response = await graphClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync(hrm);

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    // Deserialize into WorkbookRangeFont object.
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    WorkbookRangeFont updatedFontObject = graphClient.HttpProvider.Serializer.DeserializeObject<WorkbookRangeFont>(content);
}
```

[Issue #233](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/233)